# Set a spatial index on a set of rows (without table) in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-index

I got a giant geometry that I retrieve from an API and I break it into smaller pieces with `ST_Subdivide`.
Right after, I'm inserting it into a temporary table (which is indexed and only contains a geometry column), I do all my calculations and then I truncate the table.
What I'm wondering is if I could index the set of rows returned by `ST_Subdivide` without having to insert it into a temporary table.

PostGIS version : 2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: That is not implemented. An RDB is not meant to be an ETL service.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification